# Sticky table header border is overlapped by <td> elements

Tags: css

I'm using a package called ngx-virtual-scroller to implement virtual scroll for the table. It has an option to make the headers sticky -  the Javascript for that just manipulates `translateY()` of `thead` . I'm also using Bootstrap.

The issue is that, when scrolling through the table, the contents of the `<td>` elements renders on top of the borders of the header.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiHP2.png)

Code:

```html
 <virtual-scroller #scroll [items]="items" [stripedTable]="true">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered">
            <thead #header>
                <th>Some header</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody #container>
                <tr>
                    <td> Some content </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</virtual-scroller>
```

```css
virtual-scroller {
    height: calc(100% - 2rem);
    width: 100%;
    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;

    th {
        background-color: white;
        background-clip: padding-box;
    }
}
```

Changing the `border-collapse` to `separate` doesn't work. Using `box-shadow` instead of borders doesn't work. I'm losing it!

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of this: `background-clip: padding-box;`?

Comment: instead transform:translate, use position:relative and coordonates to keep your th/td/thead on sight . you won't have to deal with the side effect of transform